# How to do stored in place adjoin in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to lisp and I'm looking for a function to do a stored in place adjoin, is there any? i found the pushnew macro but it seems to work on items not lists.

```
(pushnew '((1)) '((1) (1 2) (1 2 3)))
(pushnew '(1) lst) => ((1) (1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PUSHNEW` is the modifying version of `ADJOIN`. You need to use the proper `:TEST` argument for comparing the kind of elements the list contains (such as `#'EQUAL` for lists).

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *list* (list (list 1)
                                    (list 1 2)
                                    (list 1 2 3)))
*LIST*
CL-USER> (adjoin '(1) *list*)                ; Adds
((1) (1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
CL-USER> (adjoin '(1) *list* :test #'equal)  ; Doesn't add
((1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
CL-USER> (pushnew '(1) *list*)               ; Pushes
((1) (1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
CL-USER> *list*
((1) (1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
CL-USER> (pushnew '(1) *list* :test #'equal) ; Doesn't push
((1) (1) (1 2) (1 2 3))
```